# append attribute value to element using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I can't find anything either here or in the lxml documentation.

I have an element which has an attribute already, I simply need to append a value to that existing attribute. If I try to use `myelement.set('animals', 'dog')`, then the attribute animal in this example is overwritten. What is the trick to append another value to existing attribute.

Example of existing element: `<para animals="cat" />`

What I ultimately want to achieve would be: `<para animals="cat dog" />`

While I could turn this into a string, perform this operation, then reencode it and replace the element, that just doesn't feel like the right way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Use string concatenation? `myelement.set('animals', myelement.get('animals') + ' dog')`?

Comment: If the attribute might not exist you'll need to add a condition that checks that first.

Comment: That does indeed work. Seems odd there's not a better way, but it does solve my issue.

Comment: Share the original xml and the desired xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to change only the string of the element attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml_str="""<root><para animals="cat" /></root>"""

f = StringIO(xml_str)

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "para":
        elem.set("animals" , elem.get('animals')+" dog")

ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<root><para animals="cat dog" /></root>
```